# React : TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderInput' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call the render Input method from render Hobbies method but it is giving an error saying that the render Input property is undefined. I'm not getting the exact issue. It would be great if someone could tell me what is the problem in my code ? Thanks in advance.

---

Here's the code:

### UserForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm,FieldArray } from 'redux-form'
import Multiselect from 'react-widgets/lib/Multiselect'
import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css'

class UserForm extends Component {
    renderInput(formProps) {
        const className = `field ${formProps.meta.error && formProps.meta.touched ?
            'error' : ''}`
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label>{formProps.label}</label>
                <input {...formProps.input} type={formProps.type} max={formProps.max} autoComplete='off'
                    label={formProps.label} id={formProps.id} placeholder={formProps.placeholder}
                    checked={formProps.input.value} value={formProps.input.value} />
                {formProps.meta.touched &&
                    (formProps.meta.error && <span>{formProps.meta.error}</span>)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderMultiselect({ input, ...rest }) {
        return (<Multiselect {...input}
            onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
            value={input.value || []}
            {...rest} />)
    }

    renderHobbies({ fields, meta: { error } }) {return(
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add Hobby</button>
          </li>
          {fields.map((hobby, index) =>
            <li key={index}>
              <button
                type="button"
                title="Remove Hobby"
                onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
              <Field
                name={hobby}
                type="text"
                component={this.renderInput}
                label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}/>
            </li>
          )}
          {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
        </ul>
      )
          }

    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        console.log('formValues', formValues)
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    }


    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        const current = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
        let optionsList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Travelling' }, { id: 2, name: 'Reading' }, { id: 3, name: 'Gaming' }]
        let items = [{ name: 'Travelling', value: 'Travelling' }, { name: 'Reading', value: 'Reading' }, { name: 'Gaming', value: 'Gaming' }]
        const colleges = ['Pune University', 'S.P.College', 'F.C College']
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
                    className='ui form error'>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>FullName</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='fullname' component={this.renderInput}
                                type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='Full Name'
                                validate={[required, minLength3]} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>

                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Address</label>

                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='address' component={this.renderInput}
                                type='text' placeholder='Address'
                                validate={[required, maxLength25]} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>BirthDate</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field
                                name='birthdate'
                                type='date'
                                max={current}
                                component={this.renderInput}
                                validate={required}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Select Your Gender</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-1 ui radio'>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Male</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='male'
                                    className='ui input' />{' '}
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Female</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='female'
                                />{' '}
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Other</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='other'
                                />{' '}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Select Your Hobbies</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field
                                name='hobbies'
                                component={this.renderMultiselect}
                                data={['Travelling', 'Gaming', 'Reading', 'Drawing']} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <FieldArray name='hobbies' component={this.renderHobbies}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Select College</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='college' component='select' placeholder='Select College' validate={required}>
                                <option value="">Select a college</option>
                                {colleges.map(collegeOption => (
                                    <option value={collegeOption} key={collegeOption}>
                                        {collegeOption}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </Field>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type='submit' className='ui button'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}


const required = value => (value || typeof value === 'number' ? undefined : 'Required')
const maxLength = max => value => value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters 
or less`: undefined
const maxLength25 = maxLength(25)
const minLength = min => value => value && value.length < min ? `Must be ${min} characters or 
more`: undefined
const minLength3 = minLength(3)

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'userform'
})(UserForm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the scope problem,
**this** is undefined in renderHobbies.

just binding the renderHobbies will work

```
 <div>
   <FieldArray name='hobbies' component={this.renderHobbies.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
```